# is there a provisioning for inspecting a winJs html file

Tags: microsoft-metro

winJs application are simple html Applications. Xaml c# provides an interface view where we can look at the design drag drop elements.

Is there a Way to Debug a winJS application like firebug or inspect element in Google Chrome. running every time in the simulator to check  whether code is working or not has become a tedious Job. Any alternative please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there's a kind of firebug as you mentioned But it is also known as Dom Explorer

The DOM Explorer is available only while in debug mode.

Make sure you have the script debugger selected, start debugging (F5), then go to Debug -> Windows -> DOM Explorer.

Here's a link to study the details

[Dom Explorer from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/6d156cff-36c6-425a-acf8-e1f02d4f7869#InteractiveDebugging)